# RMagick - how to create a thumbnail with an automatic height?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

I am using RMagick for creating thumbnails like this:

```
    img = Magick::Image.read(image_url).first
    target = Magick::Image.new(110, 110) do
      self.background_color = 'white'
    end
    img.resize_to_fit!(110, 110)
    target.composite(img, Magick::CenterGravity, Magick::CopyCompositeOp).write(thumb_path)
```

This works well - I'll load the current image, create a "space" for the new thumb and then will place it there.

However, I would need to create a thumb where would be the width **110px** and the height would be automatically counted... How to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'd rather use `resize_to_fill!`

[Doc here](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#resize_to_fill_bang)

Answer (score 0):

```
image = Magick::Image.read(image_url).first
image.format = "JPG"
image.change_geometry!("110X110") { |cols, rows| image.thumbnail! cols, rows }
image.write("<path to save thumbnail>")
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and this approach seems to be working. However, when I resize image with RMagick, the new image is a little bit blurred. How to fix this issue (I didn't specify the image format)?

Comment: This thumbnail dimension is very small, So when you will display it in some larger size it will get blurred. If you want it to be displayed on browser better increase dimension a bit while resizing it through RMagic and then set the required display width in HTML View.

Comment: I've tried this for a thumbnail 600x600 (the original image size was 1200x1000) and it was a bit blurred. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I added the instructions to sharpen the image to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be super easy! ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick both maintain aspect ratios properly, so in your case, just give the max width you want the image to be. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry to learn more about the magick dimension operators.

If you find that you're ruby process' RAM consumption is growing, you may want to switch to an external-exec image library, like https://github.com/mceachen/micro_magick. Also, switching to GraphicsMagick is an all-around win, BTW, giving better image encoding and in less time.

```
require 'micro_magick'
img = MicroMagick::Convert.new("input.png")
img.resize("110") # this restricts to width, if you want to restrict to height, use "x345"
img.unsharp(1.5) # This runs an "unsharp mask" convolution filter, and is optional
img.write("output.png")
```